# Send Ionic 3 Local Notification every day at a specific time

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have added the Ionic 3 local notification plugin to my project using these commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification
npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications
```

I added all dependencies on my constructor.

My code is:

```
let year = new Date().getFullYear();
let month = new Date().getMonth();
let day = new Date().getDate();

let time1 = new Date(year, month, day, 10, 00, 0, 0);
let time2 = new Date(year, month, day, 12, 00, 0, 0);

this.localNotifications.schedule([
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'My first notification',
    text: 'First notification test one',
    trigger: { at: new Date(time1) },
    data: {"id": 1, "name": "Mr. A"}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'My Second notification',
    text: 'Second notification on 12 pm',
    trigger: { at: new Date(time2) },
    data: {"id": 2, "name": "Mr. B"}
  }
]);
```

It works fine for the current day app start, but I want to send a notification **every day** at the specified time.

I want local notifications specifically, not push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a daily repeated notification, you need to use an `every:"day"` (or interval in minutes: `every: 24*60`)  and a `firstAt` property with the date when the notification will be triggered for the first time. Try this code

```
let year = new Date().getFullYear();
let month = new Date().getMonth();
let day = new Date().getDate();

let time1 = new Date(year, month, day, 10, 00, 0, 0);
let time2 = new Date(year, month, day, 12, 00, 0, 0);

this.localNotifications.schedule([
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'My first notification',
    text: 'First notification test one',
    firstAt: new Date(time1),
    every: 24*60,
    data: {"id": 1, "name": "Mr. A"}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'My Second notification',
    text: 'Second notification on 12 pm',
    firstAt: new Date(time2),
    every: 24*60,
    data: {"id": 2, "name": "Mr. B"}
  }
]);
```

Comment: Not working. It shows type script error. **firstAt** does not exist in type **ILocalNotification | ILocalNotification[]**

Comment: Strange because that exists in the docs https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Comment: I am also strange. don't know why this is not working in my code. I found a sample code which one is working for me.

`cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    title: 'Happy Birthday!!!',
    trigger: { every: { month: 4, day: 24, hour: 9, minute: 0 } }
});`

Comment: But this is not going to run daily?

Comment: If I remove **month** and **day** from trigger then it works daily.

Comment: @AmanullahAman if i remove month and day the notification wiil go in a infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

In their codebase is shown (commented) that you could achieve this by doing this

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
 text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
 trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600)},
 led: 'FF0000',
 sound: null});
```

Now, if you have to send a notification every day at the same time you could either:
**1 -**  schedule tenths of notifications and check each time a user opens your app 
**2 -** re-schedule a notification each time the user opens up a notification already received.

Answer (score -1):

In order to make a daily repeated notification, you need to use an `every:"day"` and a `firstAt` property with the date when the notification will be triggered for the first time.

**Note**: Unlike cordova plugin in Ionic 3 `firstAt` property needs to be wrapped in `trigger` property. You can find more information in [Ionic Local Notification Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/#usage).

Try this code

```
let year = new Date().getFullYear();
let month = new Date().getMonth();
let day = new Date().getDate();

let time1 = new Date(year, month, day, 10, 00, 0, 0);
let time2 = new Date(year, month, day, 12, 00, 0, 0);

this.localNotifications.schedule([
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'My first notification',
    text: 'First notification test one',
    trigger: {firstAt: new Date(time1)},
    every: every: "day"
    data: {"id": 1, "name": "Mr. A"}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'My Second notification',
    text: 'Second notification on 12 pm',
    trigger: {firstAt: new Date(time2)}, 
    every: "day",  //"day","hour","minute","week" can be used
    data: {"id": 2, "name": "Mr. B"}
  }
]);
```