# Ionic Local Notification Every Day starting specific date

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to set every day notification starting from day and time that use choose from date picker, below its my code but when I choose firstat the plugin changing the time and date, if I remove the every:"day" then I get the correct date and time

```
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
          id: this.id,
          title: this.data.description,
          text: 'Daily Payment Reminder for '+ this.data.description+ ' '+ 'Amount: €' + this.data.amount,
          trigger: {count:1 ,firstAt:new Date(this.data.date) },
          every: "day",
          data: {"id": this.id, "name": this.id},     
          foreground: true,  

          actions: [
            { id: 'yes', title: 'Yes' },
            { id: 'no',  title: 'No' }
          ], 
       });
```

Comment: `var date = new Date(this.data.date+" "+this.data.time);
  console.log(date);
  this.localNotifications.schedule({
     text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
     at: date,
     led: 'FF0000'
  });`Try this.

Comment: @Najamussaqib Hello, thank you for your reply, the var this.data.date contain date and time also I want this notification to repeated every day after from the day that user choose from date picker

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860955/send-ionic-3-local-notification-every-day-at-a-specific-time

Comment: I try it but when I use the every:'day' the plugin changed the date and time for some reason @Najamussaqib

Comment: try to open an Issue on plugin's repo.